# Developer Console doesn't work

Tags: developer-console

when I try to open the developer console it keeps loading.

[image]

Finally it stays like this:

[image]

And I can't access any of the tabs.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can reset to get it working again? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try another browser. If you have any addons or extensions,  disable it. Clear the cache and make sure you have Author apex permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps below taken from this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332898&type=1&mode=1)

1. Login and open Developer Console by Chrome
2. Open Developer tools and select Network
3. Upon reload on Developer Console
   You will see the following request to get IDEWorkspace
   `https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Name%2C%20Content%20FROM%20IDEWorkspace%20WHERE%20Id%3D%271deO00000004EkkIAE%27`
   ID of IDEWorkspace is "1deO00000004EkkIAE".
4. Login to Workbench and go to REST Explorer
5. do GET for `/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/1deO00000004EkkIAE`You will see the content of IDEWorkspace
6. Select DELETE. This will delete the workspace
7. Re-open Developer Console
   You will see that menus are available.
8. Choose an existing workspace or create a new workspace

Also, try to have minimum tabs opened at a time when working in the developer console, since multiple tabs opened increases the load time. Sometimes, as a workaround , when a developer console opens in a new window, copy the url from the new window and paste it in the same window, from where you have opened developer console.

Comment: thanks a lot, that works for me.